# Revert tag synonym [mysqldb] -> [mysql]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[mysqldb](/questions/tagged/mysqldb) is currently [a tag synonym for](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/synonyms) [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) and I think it shouldn't be

Asking a question involving [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#mysqldb) (while obviously it *uses* MySQL), is not quite the same as asking a question that is **about** MySQL.  [This question in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010042/mysql-get-column-name-or-alias-from-query/5010112#5010112) really has nothing to do with MySQL in particular, but has everything to do with MySQLdb.  If anything, it should be a tag synonym of [mysql-python](/questions/tagged/mysql-python), as that is the "proper" name of the package (though it's largely referred to as just "MySQLdb").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old synonym has been removed, it was an over-generalization and incorrect.

The [new synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql-python/synonyms) is [mysqldb](/questions/tagged/mysqldb) -> [mysql-python](/questions/tagged/mysql-python)

I can't undo the renames so easily because the retagged questions are mixed in with all other legitimate [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) related questions, but all *future* renames will be more correct.