# What was the reason for not using nested tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-hierarchy

**Note: this is a general interest question, rather than a feature request.**

I noticed that [nested tags have been discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags), and declined. However, there was no reason given - just this from Jeff Atwood:

> we will not be doing trees, in any way, shape or form

By nested tags, I mean something like:

```
- PHP
  - Symfony
  - PHP 5

- Ruby
  - Rails

- Frameworks
  - Symfony
  - Rails
```

so that if you look at

- *Frameworks* - you see everything from *Symfony* and *Rails*
- *PHP* - you see everything from *PHP5* and *Symfony*
- *Symfony* - you see only *Symfony*

I'm wondering what the logic behind the rejection was, because a project that I'm working on is considering something like this. Was it a technical decision (as in, too complicated to implement on the backend)? A UX decision (as in, it makes the UX too complicated)?

[This other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91493/tag-synonyms-and-revisitation-of-hierarchical-tags) suggests it was mostly to do with the implications on a user's reputation. Is that the case?

---

APPENDED

Some other relevant questions:

- [A proposal for tag hierarchy on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so)
- [Tag hierarchy absence - design reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45377/tag-hierarchy-absence-design-reasons)
- [Tag hierarchy to browse through tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6514/tag-hierarchy-to-browse-through-tags)

And this [blog post](http://www.itauthor.com/2009/03/15/programmers-love-hierarchy-normal-people-hate-that/) seems to refer to [Podcast #45](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/podcast-45/). [This](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W29035#47m54s) exchange seems to be the explanation:

> Atwood:   … programmers love hierarchy, to a degree that they don't
> even understand how different they are than the public in this regard.
> Like they love putting everything in this little bucket, that goes in
> this little bucket, which is this sub-bucket of this and this, and
> normal people hate that. And threading is totally a manifestation of
> that and it drives me crazy that a lot of programmers can't see that
> they're like immediately like: "Oh, threading is good. I love
> threading. What are you talking about?" You know? They can't see it at
> all.
>
> Spolsky:   Right, right.
>
> Atwood:   It's like myopia.
>
> Spolsky:   Yeh. I mean it's really a function of the size of the
> group, and one thing I've learned through years and years of usability
> testing is that anything that smacks of a hierarchy or a tree is not
> going to be understandable to the average, non-technical user.
>
> Atwood:   Yeh.
>
> Spolsky:   You just have to learn that: if it's a tree, or a
> hierarchy, like eighty per cent of the regular people are going to get
> confused and not quite get it.

Comment: [balpha's answer might shed more light](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2799/163863)... now you just need to track down *that* podcast ;)

Comment: @Matt thanks for the reference to the podcast - I found it, and have added a key quote to the question.

Comment: Related: [We need meta tags to be able to organize and search tags easily](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1620/95735)