# Count related tags fractionally when determining eligibility for voting on synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Tag synonymization requests here on Meta [tend](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91423/please-merge-the-tag-tableviewcell-into-uitableviewcell) to [be made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124608/relax-tag-synonym-voting-rules) by people who have good knowledge of the relevant domain, but lack upvotes on the particular tag. This [is good in that it can produce community involvement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91502/159251), but we [already have a system for community input](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms); the actual tag synonym proposal and voting features. Those are [almost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141709/remove-or-reduce-restrictions-from-tag-synonym-submission-process#comment401305_141709) [useless](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124608/relax-tag-synonym-voting-rules#comment334718_124608) for non-headliner tags, though.

The tag system has a good idea about what tags are connected to each other semantically just from their coincidence on questions; there's a "related" list on every tag page. We should use that information to make the tag synonym system work better. If a user knows a thing or two about [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c), there's a good chance he knows a least a half a thing about [nsscanner](/questions/tagged/nsscanner).

Thus, in calculating eligibility for the tag synonym system, we should count votes on closely-related tags as some fraction of a vote directly on the tag. Maybe half a vote; maybe there can even be a drop-off as the tags become less-closely related.

**Credits:** This is supported by jmac's *excellent* post [Improving Tag Synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204244/improving-tag-synonyms), which was in turn sprouted from Jon Ericson's [Does the tag synonym suggestion system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work) My [hat's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFmhn.png) off to them for laying all that groundwork. The suggestion itself was actually originally made in [RobW's answer to Jon's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128874/); I'm stealing it and reposting it as a full request.