# The meta.stackexchange question 79453 should be moved to meta.stackoverflow

Tags: support, bug, meta, migration, mso-mse-split

The question [Revert tag synonym [mysqldb] -> [mysql]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79453/) should be moved to https://meta.stackoverflow.com.
I refer to the **The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange**, saying:

> [W]hich questions should be migrated from here to [meta.stackoverflow]? Obviously site-specific things like the retag-requests, and perhaps questions with the stackoverflow tag. *Anything that is 100% wholly specific to Stack Overflow and not generalizable to the rest of the network should be moved over.*
>   [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015)

If you agree with me that this question is indeed *100% wholly specific to Stack Overflow* - and if you have the required privilege/reputation to do so - go ahead and move this question to Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's an 8.5 year old question with an issue that has been resolved. Why should it still be moved?

Comment: [Questions more than two months old can't be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/566903)

Comment: @Bart. Because Tim Post said so: **We'll just migrate SO specific content back to the new MSO?** - "Not initially, _**but yes, eventually**_". [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/) - Or should I interpret "Not initially" to mean "Not in this century"?

Comment: Tim Post said many things and promised many things. Many of those were never done.

Answer (score 13):

There are thousands of these questions, posted before the MSO/MSE split.

No point moving them all (can't be automated since we can't know for sure which are off topic and which are not), so best action is to just leave them alone, maybe after closing as "Specific to one site" so nobody will waste time by mistake by posting answer.

Comment: A similar problem was brought up elsewhere; are mods able to move it?

Comment: @Zoe ordinary mods can't, but pretty sure dev/CM can. Or worst case direct database access like Shog sometimes does.

Comment: Exactly where in my post did you read that I asked for _anything_ to be automated?

Comment: @Henke "There are thousands of these" - so it's pointless to post a new question on MSE or flag each to ask for migration. Hence, automatic migration would be ideal. There is nothing special in the question you linked to. It is just one of those thousands SO-specific questions lying here since the olden days.

Answer (score 8):

The specific post you cite is a very old post from 2012, that very *roughly* indicates the criteria for which questions would be migrated to the new Meta Stack Overflow once the split happens.

However, a [much later post published as the split was about to take place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215677/when-mse-splits-from-mso-what-content-will-be-quickly-migrated-back-to-mso) mentioned that only **recent and unresolved** Stack Overflow-specific questions would be migrated. The question you cite had already been resolved earlier and was posted three years before the split, so it didn't meet those criteria and wasn't migrated. To quote from that post:

> However, ***please do not [request migration] just for the sake of bucketing or sorting content*** - unless it's very recent and seemingly unresolved, we'll probably decline.

It's also worth noting that [questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) by normal users; I suggest reading the reasons why that is the case. While it technically *is* possible for Stack Exchange staff to bypass this policy, it is *very rarely* done except under *exceptional* circumstances.

We are currently in the process of closing older Stack Overflow-specific content that wasn't migrated; as there are a lot of these questions laying around, and as doing so is not an active, urgent priority, it takes some time.